How to open flutter apk template in VS Code?
I'm new to Flutter and VS Code and spent yesterday getting my feet wet with them using a couple YouTube tutorials. After searching Git Hub and a couple other paid sites, I downloaded a zipped "Login UI" template file to practice with. I tried to open it in VS Code with no success. How do I open it in VS Code? It appears it is an apk file that has alot of files in it that I was using yesterday (lib, Android, yaml, etc).
Thanks!
